# File sharing services with locking

Tags: windows, file, locking, shared, filelock

I have a file server and it is connected to 10 windows nodes using LAN . In a production shared folder we are having a big data with some software codes . every developers are using the same file . Some times User A didn't know User B is using the file .
So my actual question is , Is there any option or any shared storage mechanism that actually help this scenario?

If USER-A modifying a file rest of the users only need read only permission , after he done his work other users can able to work with it .

Any help ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689597/code-repository-whats-a-good-one

Comment: This is nothing to do with the server, and everything to do with what software you're using to edit the files.  (Or the fact that you're editing them directly at all, rather than using [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_version_control_software).)